# Is it possible to get the cursor for the beginning of a query so that a future run of the query can use it as an end_cursor?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to render a page that starts with the first n entities of a given model and have the page regularly check for new items. Similar to how, say, twitter renders a page of tweets and then prompts you with "6 newer tweets" when they are available.

I currently do this by:

```
query = Item.all()
query.order("-created")
query.fetch(100)
cursor = query.cursor()
timestamp = time.time()
# render a page storing cursor and timestamp so it can request for older items
# & regularly check for newer ones.
```

When I receive a request for updates, with a timestamp, I run a query that filters out items before that timestamp.

I was wondering if there was a way to do it as follows (and whether this would be faster):

- grab a cursor for the beginning, let's call this update_cursor
- fetch data, etc. as before.

When page asks for updates (and provides an update_cursor) perform same query but with `query.with_cursor(end_cursor=update_cursor)` and `query.run()` instead of fetch() so that it grabs me all the items until the point I started from previously.

I've tried to fetch 0 entities and look at the cursor, but that just gives me an empty string.

Is this possible (and if it is, is measurably faster than the timestamp method)? Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: `query.with_cursor()` needs a starting cursor as first parameter; you are just passing the `end_cursor` so it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of elements being at the beginning of the index they are at the end the cursor? This could help you be at the newest entity of your model (The only thing I am not sure if you would get a valid cursor after the last element of the query). next when you are pulling updates just start your query from that cursor and fetch the newest entities.

I have not tried this myself but it could work, give it a try and let me know how it goes.